# Product Attribute with attribute set using insaller script

Tags: attributes, installation, magento-1.7

I am facing a problem regarding creating attribute and attribute set using installer script.attribute set and attribute is created but the problem is attributes are assigned to all attribute set instead of only custom one creating with installer script.

following is my installer script:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
try{
$sNewSetName = 'Product Bundler Package';
$iCatalogProductEntityTypeId = (int) $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');

$oAttributeset = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
->setEntityTypeId($iCatalogProductEntityTypeId)
->setAttributeSetName($sNewSetName);

if ($oAttributeset->validate()) {
$oAttributeset
    ->save()
    ->initFromSkeleton($installer->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', 'Default'))
    ->save();
 }
else {
   Mage::log('Attributeset with name ' . $sNewSetName . ' already exists.');
   }
  }
  catch(Exception $ex){
 Mage::log('Attributeset with name ' . $sNewSetName . ' already exists.');

}


$installer->addAttributeGroup('catalog_product', 'Product Bundler Package', 'Bundled Package Data', 1000);

$data1= array (
    'attribute_set' =>  'Product Bundler Package',
    'group' => 'Bundled Package Data',
    'label'    => 'Preset1 name',
    'visible'     => true,
    'type'     => 'varchar', 
    'input'    => 'text',
    'system'   => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => 1, 
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','bundle_preset1_name',$data1);

  $data2= array (
    'attribute_set' =>  'Product Bundler Package',
    'group'    => 'Bundled Package Data',
    'label'    => 'Preset2 name',
    'visible'  => true,
    'type'     => 'varchar', 
    'input'    => 'text',
    'system'   => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => 1, 
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','bundle_preset2_name',$data2);

$data3= array (
    'attribute_set' =>  'Product Bundler Package',
    'group' => 'Bundled Package Data',
    'label'    => 'Preset3 name',
    'visible'     => true,
    'type'     => 'varchar', 
    'input'    => 'text',
    'system'   => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => 1, 
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','bundle_preset3_name',$data3);

$data4 = array (
    'attribute_set' =>  'Product Bundler Package',
    'group' => 'Bundled Package Data',
    'label'    => 'Preset4 name',
    'visible'     => true,
    'type'     => 'varchar', 
    'input'    => 'text',
    'system'   => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => 1, 
);
   $attribute =  $installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','bundle_preset4_name',$data4);


$installer->endSetup();
 ?>
```

I want to create custom attributes with attribute set name "Product Bundler Package" and assign all attribute to that attribute set only.

Kindly help me to resolve it.

Comment: is any one there to resolve the issue???

Answer (score 0):

You can add following code before $installer->endSetUp();

```
/*delete the group from default attribute set in the end of the script */
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$write = $resource->getConnection('write');
$groupTable = $installer->getTable('eav_attribute_group');
$defaultSetId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($iCatalogProductEntityTypeId);
$groupNameToRemove = 'Bundled Package Data';
$write->query("Delete from $groupTable where attribute_set_id=$defaultSetId and attribute_group_name='$groupNameToRemove'");
```